# what is the unique id of informix temp table?

Tags: java, spring, informix

I create a temp table which consist of several table with `UNION ALL` statement like here below. I want later map this table to the entity for repository in spring. With other words I wanna map temp table to entity in spring jpa or hibernate.

```
select * from name  UNION ALL 
select * from soft where id >3 
into temp namesoft_tmp
```

I tried the following.

```
select * from namesoft_tmp
```

but i can't see what is the column which can point me to the conclusion that this is primary key.

**What is the unique id(primary key) of table namesoft_tmp?**

How can i add auto generated id to temp table?

How can i excute select statement based on unique id?**

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I can't quite understand what you want.

Comment: You can use the CREATE INDEX statement to create indexes on a temporary table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. where should i put CREATE INDEX in my query mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the result of a UNION ALL query does not have a primary key; there is no guarantee that there are not duplicate rows in the result set.

Imagine a table describing the table of elements — called `elements`.

```
SELECT * FROM elements WHERE atomic_number < 10
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM elements WHERE symbol MATCHES '[A-F]*'
INTO TEMP union_all;
```

Here, the elements Boron (B), Carbon (C), Beryllium (Be) and Fluorine (F) are all listed twice.

However, you can use:

```
SELECT ROWID, * FROM union_all ORDER BY atomic_number;
```

to get a unique identifier, the ROWID, in the result set.  Note that this unique identifier is unique at any given time, but is not guaranteed to be stable.  If you delete rows and add them again, the ROWID of the replaced rows may be different from before.  But the ROWID will be unique until you edit the table.

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------------+-----------+--------+-------+
| rowid | atomic | symbol | name         | atomic    | period | group |
|       | number |        |              | weight    |        |       |
+-------+--------+--------+--------------+-----------+--------+-------+
|   257 |      1 | H      | Hydrogen     |    1.0079 |      1 | 1     |
|   258 |      2 | He     | Helium       |    4.0026 |      1 | 18    |
|   259 |      3 | Li     | Lithium      |    6.9410 |      2 | 1     |
|   260 |      4 | Be     | Beryllium    |    9.0122 |      2 | 2     |
|   266 |      4 | Be     | Beryllium    |    9.0122 |      2 | 2     |
|   267 |      5 | B      | Boron        |   10.8110 |      2 | 13    |
|   261 |      5 | B      | Boron        |   10.8110 |      2 | 13    |
|   268 |      6 | C      | Carbon       |   12.0110 |      2 | 14    |
|   262 |      6 | C      | Carbon       |   12.0110 |      2 | 14    |
|   263 |      7 | N      | Nitrogen     |   14.0070 |      2 | 15    |
|   264 |      8 | O      | Oxygen       |   15.9990 |      2 | 16    |
|   265 |      9 | F      | Fluorine     |   18.9980 |      2 | 17    |
|   269 |      9 | F      | Fluorine     |   18.9980 |      2 | 17    |
|   270 |     13 | Al     | Aluminium    |   26.9820 |      3 | 13    |
|   271 |     17 | Cl     | Chlorine     |   35.4530 |      3 | 17    |
|   272 |     18 | Ar     | Argon        |   39.9480 |      3 | 18    |
|   273 |     20 | Ca     | Calcium      |   40.0780 |      4 | 2     |
|   274 |     24 | Cr     | Chromium     |   51.9960 |      4 | 6     |
|   275 |     26 | Fe     | Iron         |   55.8450 |      4 | 8     |
|   276 |     27 | Co     | Cobalt       |   58.9330 |      4 | 9     |
|   277 |     29 | Cu     | Copper       |   63.5460 |      4 | 11    |
|   278 |     33 | As     | Arsenic      |   74.9220 |      4 | 15    |
|   279 |     35 | Br     | Bromine      |   79.9040 |      4 | 17    |
|   280 |     47 | Ag     | Silver       |  107.8700 |      5 | 11    |
|   281 |     48 | Cd     | Cadmium      |  112.4100 |      5 | 12    |
|   282 |     55 | Cs     | Caesium      |  132.9100 |      6 | 1     |
|   283 |     56 | Ba     | Barium       |  137.3300 |      6 | 2     |
|   284 |     58 | Ce     | Cerium       |  140.1200 |      6 | L     |
|   285 |     63 | Eu     | Europium     |  151.9600 |      6 | L     |
|   286 |     66 | Dy     | Dyprosium    |  162.5000 |      6 | L     |
|   287 |     68 | Er     | Erbium       |  167.2600 |      6 | L     |
|   288 |     79 | Au     | Gold         |  196.9700 |      6 | 11    |
|   289 |     83 | Bi     | Bismuth      |  208.9800 |      6 | 15    |
|   290 |     85 | At     | Astatine     |  209.9900 |      6 | 17    |
|   291 |     87 | Fr     | Francium     |  223.0200 |      7 | 1     |
|   292 |     89 | Ac     | Actinium     |  227.0300 |      7 | A     |
|   293 |     95 | Am     | Americium    |  243.0600 |      7 | A     |
|   294 |     96 | Cm     | Curium       |  247.0700 |      7 | A     |
|   295 |     97 | Bk     | Berkelium    |  247.0700 |      7 | A     |
|   296 |     98 | Cf     | Californium  |  251.0800 |      7 | A     |
|   297 |     99 | Es     | Einsteinium  |  252.0800 |      7 | A     |
|   298 |    100 | Fm     | Fermium      |  257.1000 |      7 | A     |
|   299 |    105 | Db     | Dubnium      |  270.1300 |      7 | 5     |
|   300 |    107 | Bh     | Bohrium      |  270.1300 |      7 | 7     |
|   301 |    110 | Ds     | Darmstadtium |  281.1700 |      7 | 10    |
|   302 |    112 | Cn     | Copernicium  |  285.1800 |      7 | 12    |
|   303 |    114 | Fl     | Flerovium    |  289.1900 |      7 | 14    |
+-------+--------+--------+--------------+-----------+--------+-------+
```